# Including Assets (CSS, JS) in Symfony 4 / Twig Template

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig, symfony4

Im learning Symfony and trying to set up a boilerplate app in Symfony 4

[This Symfony document](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html) describes how to include assets in your page, namely using the `asset` package like so..

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="Symfony!" />

<link href="{{ asset('css/blog.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have installed this package and trying to link to a css file in my `/public` directory.

I know Symfony recommends placing assets in an `/assets` folder at the root, but I would like to avoid this if possible. It makes more sense to me to place assets in the public directory.

My Twig base template is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>

        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link href="{{ asset('public/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</html>
```

**Problem**

When I load the route/page/template, the linked css is rendered as a simple link from the root (as if Im linking it as `<link href="public/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />` - there is of course no route set for `public/*` and this returns `404/Not Found`.

Its as if the `asset()` function is not even used.

**Ive tried**

- Restarting my local Symfony server
- moving the asset to an `assets` folder at the root at adjusting the link accordingly
- verifying that the `asset` package was installed (it is)
- googling this issue (nothing for Symfony 4)

**Questions**

- How can I let Symfony know that the `public/*` path is a filesystem path to assets, NOT a URL route, and include my assets successfully?
- Is there such a feature to set a default location for assets other than the recommended `/assets` folder at the root?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Paths in the `asset` function should be relative to your public directory, not the project root.

So, pretending your server's docroot is `public_html`, and an asset is in `public_html/css/main.css`, the asset call would be `{{ asset('css/main.css') }}`.

Additional note: The asset function doesn't give you the ability to put assets outside the public directory. They *must* be in the public directory.

Comment: I dont get it. Before symfony 3.4 it was easy. In symfony 3.4/4 is horrible

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html

I have to put assets in public - ok. but then instal another dependency manger, build configs, and those configs load into twig... Bad idea.

Comment: @zoore That is only if you choose to use Encore. You do not have to. Twig's asset function remains the same. Also, those configs do not "load into Twig". You're just using `asset` in Twig to point to where Encore builds assets, same as any other static asset.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly maybe you have to add the asset functionality to Symfony:

```
composer require symfony/asset
```

Then you should to use in Twig temlate the relative path to your public directory:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

for the `public/css/style.css` style file.

*BTW it is also works for Symfony 5.*

Answer (score 0):

Check if webpack is watching files ... (yarn watch) After hours of searching for an answer one of my project team members asked if I had that running ={  Worked immediately after that.